# Use Factory Pattern with Generics

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am currently learning how to write "better" Code in Java using common patterns. What I am facing now is the following:

I have several Entities such as Person, Company or City. I want to create Registries to store different instances of these entities in these registries. For this I created the following class:

```
public class MockUpRegistry<K, V> implements IRegistry<K, V>{

    HashMap<K, V> items = null;

    public MockUpRegistry() {
        items = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addMockUp(K key, V value) {
        items.put(key, value);
    }


    public ArrayList<V> getAll() {
        ArrayList<V> allEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        for (V value : items.values()) {
            allEntries.add(value);
        };

        return  allEntries;
    }


    public V getByKey(K key) {
        return items.get(key);
    }

    public void removeByKey(K key) {
        items.remove(key);
    }
}
```

It is basically just a Skeleton to create a Registry depending on the entity type you want to store in this registry. Also, you can then use it via an interface to add, get and delete instances. For example I create a registry for Person like:

```
IRegistry personRegistry = new MockupRegistry<Integer, Person>();
```

What I was wondering now was if it makes sense to make use of the Factory Pattern to create the corresponding registry. I was thinking of something like that:

```
public class RegistryFactory {

    public static MockUpRegistry getMockUpRegistry(String entity) {
        switch (entity) {
            case "Person":
                return new MockUpRegistry<Integer, Person>();
            case "Company":
                return new MockUpRegistry<Integer, Company>();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I got to know the Factory-Pattern in the context of inheritance so I am not sure if the pattern also makes sense in my example.
I think that it is pretty easy to instantiate the different registries like that. What do you think? Can you think of any downsides/advantages of this?

Comment: No, the pattern does not make sense, because of the way the generics work; trying to return a different type based on a string is a bad idea.  Honestly, your registry class doesn't really add any value over a HashMap directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd really appreciate if you gave me some more advice. What i was actually planning to do, was to create some sort of MockUp-Database. We are working on a project with multiple microservices that depend on each other. In order to develop independently it'd be helpful to just use some sample-objects that normally these microservices would return. So for example one service uses another that returns a person instance. 
Thus, I created the MockUpRegistry that simply holds a few sample-instances of a certain entity. Can you suggest something more common for this?